# Is it safe to expose your Applovin Sdk API key?

Tags: api-key, applovin

While decompiling random android APK file, I have found the Applovin Sdk Key is publicly Accessible in manifest file.

```
<meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key" android:value="[KEY]"/>
```

is it security Issue?

Answer (score 0):

it's not a security issue.  the sdk key helps define your account but no one can access any of your data with the key.  someone could generate revenue for you if they have your key and that's about it.